# Confirmation Alert Before Sending Email with AppleScript (Microsoft Outlook)?

Tags: email, outlook, applescript

Is it possible to run an AppleScript that shows a confirmation alert after pressing the send button a message via Microsoft Outlook for Mac? The script I'm trying to run would be that if a certain email address is in the To, CC, or BCC field, this confirmation would pop up saying "Are you sure you want to send this message?" Yes = Send. No = Don't Send.

Looking at the dictionary for Outlook, my options seem limited, but I wanted to see if anyone had a solution for this.

Comment: Please state what versions of Outlook and macOS you are running.  It makes a BIG difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may NOT need an AppleScript.  Perhaps an Outlook 2011 Rule will do the job for you.

If you are running Microsoft Outlook 14.7.2 (14.7.2) [Outlook 2011] on macOS 10.11.6:

[image]

then

[image]

If you do need an AppleScript, you probably still need a Rule to trigger the script.  In the choices of the Rule, there is an AppleScript option.